# How can I copy a vector mask from one document to another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector-graphics

I "vectorized" a raster image using vector masks made with the pen tool. Now I need these masks (on separate layers) in another document. How could I copy them, to secure their vector-ness, and have them as resize-able objects?

I am using Photoshop CS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. CS5's Copy Layer function has a Target option, where I can select open documents :D

Comment: It would be appreciated if you would mark your own answer as the solution to you question :)